# Joomla 2.5 get user from external script

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to get some data from joomla 2.5 db. The script i made seems to work with old account, but i reset password it does not work anymore.
I need to change way to check username and password?
The script i was using is that:

```
//Check username and password
$rCUSRNAM = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$rCPASSWO = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

//Query db to inspect user
$query_jom = "SELECT * FROM jh23m_users WHERE username ='".$rCUSRNAM."'";
$result_jom = mysql_query($query_jom);
$row_jom = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_jom);

//Check password - joomla based
$part = explode(":", $row_jom['password']);
$salt = $part[1];
$encrypted_password = md5($rCPASSWO.$salt).":".$salt;

//Check authentication
if(!($encrypted_password == $row_jom['password'])){
echo "Invalid login details";
exit;
}

//Check user lock - joomla based
if($row_jom['block'] <> 0){
echo "Account locked, contact support";
exit;
}
$user_id = $row_jom['id'];
$username = $row_jom['username'];
$email = $row_jom['email'];
```

Comment: Why new passowrds are like that $P$DvHmNbNnC9qxfBtQQV2vmy8dw0sZ0U/ while older are like that 6ead0019210f8e867c6e7aaaba4a6ae0:P7XTlUYW8pfYP9sivLi2TscrE3ka92wf

Comment: You need to go read through the changes in the API for authentication and password encryption.  The default is no longer to use salted md5.

Comment: I downgraded to 2.5.17.

Comment: You're better off moving to strong encryption.